# SQLite Build Schema not working on sqlfiddle

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlfiddle

I am trying to create a simple sqlfiddle in sqlite (websql), but its not working. The sqlfiddle is at [Sqlite (websql) Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7)

When I press on the `Build Schema` button, it goes into the build mode but stays there forever. Also, I don't see any error message. My internet connection is very good, so it cannot be due to a broken internet connection.

**Question**

Why is the Sqlite script below not building schema in sqlfiddle? May be I am missing something very basic.

SQlite Script being used

```
create table Items (Id integer PRIMARY KEY, ParentId integer);

insert into Items (Id, ParentId) values (1,0);
```

Comment: That web site is broken regularly. Ask for your money back.

Comment: @Sunil, which browser are you using? Possibly the problem is this is WebSQL "implementation". I'm [using](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xjJGqmFVMeM14YdtrfjWsr/2) db-fiddle.com for SQLite fiddles, although that site is broken very often too.

Comment: @Stanislav Kralin,  I tried using latest Chrome and Firefox,  but the same problem in both.